# Trying to grep cygwin output from cvs commands

Tags: cygwin, cvs, grep

I am trying to find an easy way to see what files I have modified in my checked out code by running either cvs update or cvs status and limiting the output to the files I have modified.

I started by doing variations on:

```
cvs update | grep "M " // this did nothing useful.
cvs update | grep -e "M " * // this got me all the files that had "M " in them.
```

in order to only get the lines that have the M for modified. That did not work.

Someone suggested:

```
cvs status -v | grep Locally // -v prints the verbose status to ouput
```

and that also did not have the expected results. Is grep the correct tool to be using here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cvs update 2>&1 | ...` IIRC, the log output of cvs is to stderr, not stdout, so the pipe doesn't catch that by default.

Comment: Ah very nice. For some reason the & does not help but doing 

cvs status -v 2>1 | grep Locally 

totally gives me what I am looking for!

Comment: :/ That should create a file called "1". I swapped the two characters. It should be "2>&1", not "2&>1". Sorry for that.